# Taylor series of $r:x \mapsto \begin{cases} e^{-{1\over x}}, & \text{if $x>0$} \\ 0, & \text{if $x \le 0$}\end{cases}$ at $0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series

Prove the following lemma: The function $$r:x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
e^{-{1\over x}},  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x \le 0$}
\end{cases}$$  is $C^{\infty}$ (and x=0),that has necessarily zero Taylor series in $x=0$, i.e.
$$(r^{j}(0)=0))$$ for all $j$.

Any ideas how to prove this lemma?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your $r(x)$ is the Wikipedia example of an [Non-analytic smooth function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function).

For $x>0$ we know, that $r$ is $C^\infty$. The interesting part is $x=0$.
Let us therefore consider the derivatives of $\exp(-1/x)$. We know, that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}e^{-{1}/{x}} = x^{-2}e^{-1/x}= \frac{1}{M_1(x)} e^{-1/x}
\end{align}
where $M_1$ is some monomial. Repeating this process, you should be able to show, that
\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-{1}/{x}} = \sum_k \frac{1}{M_k(x)} e^{-1/x}
\end{align}
Next, you have to show that ${M_k(x)} e^{-1/x}\rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ independent of the order of the monomial, this is equivalent to showing, that $\exp(-x)x^k\rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Therefore, $r$ is $C^\infty$ with $\frac{d^j}{dx^j}r(0) = 0$.